# tkinter Label not getting updated before function call

Tags: python, tkinter

In the below code snippet (in the `convert` function) the status label is not getting set to "Processing" before the `time_consuming_func` is run. Rather it gets updated after the function. I'm using the label to indicate the program is executing the time consuming function so this defeats the purpose of having a status label.

I noticed that if I put a breakpoint just after `self.status.set("Processing")` the label does get updated.

What can I do to have the status label change correctly i.e. before the `time_consuming_func` ?

```
import os
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from typing import Any, Tuple

WINDOW_SIZE = "550x300"

FILETYPES = (("All files", "*.*"),)


def time_consuming_func():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("DONE")

class NotebookTab(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(
        self,
        master: ttk.Notebook,
        io_callbacks: Tuple[Any, Any],
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> None:
        if kwargs:
            super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        else:
            super().__init__(master)
        self.ipath = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.opath = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.status = tk.StringVar(self, value="Idle")
        assert len(io_callbacks) == 2
        self.input_callback: Any = io_callbacks[0]
        self.output_callback: Any = io_callbacks[1]
        self.create_widgets()

    def open_input(self) -> None:
        if self.input_callback == fd.askopenfilename:
            _input = self.input_callback(filetypes=FILETYPES)
        else:
            _input = self.input_callback()
        if _input:
            path = os.path.abspath(_input)
            self.ipath.set(path)

    def open_output(self) -> None:
        if self.output_callback == fd.asksaveasfilename:
            _output = self.output_callback(filetypes=FILETYPES)
        else:
            _output = self.output_callback()
        if _output:
            path = os.path.abspath(_output)
            self.opath.set(path)

    def convert(self) -> None:
        inpath = self.ipath.get()
        outpath = self.opath.get()

        self.status.set("Processing")

        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        try:
            time_consuming_func()
            # Set status to done and clear boxes
            #self.status.set("Idle")
            self.ipath.set("")
            self.opath.set("")
        except Exception:
            self.status.set("ERROR")
            showerror(
                title="Error",
                message="An unexpected error occurred."
                "Close window or press OK to view traceback",
            )
            raise

    def create_widgets(self) -> None:

        statuslbl = tk.Label(self, text="Status:")
        statuslbl.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.7, anchor="e")
        self.statusval = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.status)
        self.statusval.place(relx=0.85, rely=0.7, anchor="e")

        inputpath = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.ipath)
        inputpath.update()
        inputpath.focus_set()
        inputpath.place(y=10, x=10, relwidth=0.70, height=20)

        outputpath = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.opath)
        outputpath.update()
        outputpath.focus_set()
        outputpath.place(y=50, x=10, relwidth=0.70, height=20)

        # Buttons
        open_input_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Input", command=self.open_input)
        open_output_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Output", command=self.open_output)
        convert_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Convert", command=self.convert)

        open_input_button.pack(anchor="e", padx=20, pady=10)
        open_output_button.pack(anchor="e", padx=20, pady=10)
        convert_button.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.7, anchor=tk.CENTER)


def main() -> None:

    # Root window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Converter")
    root.resizable(True, True)
    root.geometry(WINDOW_SIZE)

    tab_parent = ttk.Notebook(root)

    file_tab = NotebookTab(
        tab_parent,
        (fd.askopenfilename, fd.asksaveasfilename),
    )
    dir_tab = NotebookTab(
        tab_parent,
        (fd.askdirectory, fd.askdirectory),
    )

    tab_parent.add(file_tab, text="File")
    tab_parent.add(dir_tab, text="Directory")
    tab_parent.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `self.update()` before try and except in `convert` function.

The problem is when `self.status.set()` is executed, it does its job perfectly, but you have used `time.sleep(10)` which cause delay in whole python interpreter, which could be solved by using `.after` method.

`self.update()` works because it updates the window before executing `time.sleep()`, so updates the whole window.

Answer (score 3):

Get familiar with the concept of [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). I made changes in line 8 and 65. However, this means that your GUI is reactive after launching the thread, which comes with a couple of risks.

```
import os
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from typing import Any, Tuple
from threading import Thread

WINDOW_SIZE = "550x300"

FILETYPES = (("All files", "*.*"),)


def time_consuming_func():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("DONE")

class NotebookTab(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(
        self,
        master: ttk.Notebook,
        io_callbacks: Tuple[Any, Any],
        **kwargs: Any,
    ) -> None:
        if kwargs:
            super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        else:
            super().__init__(master)
        self.ipath = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.opath = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.status = tk.StringVar(self, value="Idle")
        assert len(io_callbacks) == 2
        self.input_callback: Any = io_callbacks[0]
        self.output_callback: Any = io_callbacks[1]
        self.create_widgets()

    def open_input(self) -> None:
        if self.input_callback == fd.askopenfilename:
            _input = self.input_callback(filetypes=FILETYPES)
        else:
            _input = self.input_callback()
        if _input:
            path = os.path.abspath(_input)
            self.ipath.set(path)

    def open_output(self) -> None:
        if self.output_callback == fd.asksaveasfilename:
            _output = self.output_callback(filetypes=FILETYPES)
        else:
            _output = self.output_callback()
        if _output:
            path = os.path.abspath(_output)
            self.opath.set(path)

    def convert(self) -> None:
        inpath = self.ipath.get()
        outpath = self.opath.get()

        self.status.set("Processing")

        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        try:
            t = Thread(target=time_consuming_func)
            t.start()
            # time_consuming_func()
            # Set status to done and clear boxes
            #self.status.set("Idle")
            self.ipath.set("")
            self.opath.set("")
        except Exception:
            self.status.set("ERROR")
            showerror(
                title="Error",
                message="An unexpected error occurred."
                "Close window or press OK to view traceback",
            )
            raise

    def create_widgets(self) -> None:

        statuslbl = tk.Label(self, text="Status:")
        statuslbl.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.7, anchor="e")
        self.statusval = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.status)
        self.statusval.place(relx=0.85, rely=0.7, anchor="e")

        inputpath = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.ipath)
        inputpath.update()
        inputpath.focus_set()
        inputpath.place(y=10, x=10, relwidth=0.70, height=20)

        outputpath = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.opath)
        outputpath.update()
        outputpath.focus_set()
        outputpath.place(y=50, x=10, relwidth=0.70, height=20)

        # Buttons
        open_input_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Input", command=self.open_input)
        open_output_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Output", command=self.open_output)
        convert_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Convert", command=self.convert)

        open_input_button.pack(anchor="e", padx=20, pady=10)
        open_output_button.pack(anchor="e", padx=20, pady=10)
        convert_button.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.7, anchor=tk.CENTER)


def main() -> None:

    # Root window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Converter")
    root.resizable(True, True)
    root.geometry(WINDOW_SIZE)

    tab_parent = ttk.Notebook(root)

    file_tab = NotebookTab(
        tab_parent,
        (fd.askopenfilename, fd.asksaveasfilename),
    )
    dir_tab = NotebookTab(
        tab_parent,
        (fd.askdirectory, fd.askdirectory),
    )

    tab_parent.add(file_tab, text="File")
    tab_parent.add(dir_tab, text="Directory")
    tab_parent.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

#### Edit

if you want parts of your code to be executed before launching the thread, and other parts when its done, i suggest putting the parts (e.g. clearing the entry) at the end in your `time_consuming_func()`. You have other options, such as getting returns from the thread and handle those, which is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'GUI being reactive'? Also, is there any advantage to this over updating the window (via `self.update()`) as Faraaz suggested?

Comment: Its a different thing - i suppose the `self.update()` refreshes the Frame/GUI before executing the time consuming function. While your function is executed, your GUI is frozen. This is not the case with threading - your GUI is still reactive, meaning you can click buttons, resize etc. - while your heavy function is running in the background. The risk is, that you have to make sure no other function accessible by the GUI depends on your function or results from it. If it does, you might have to disable certain buttons and/or wait for the return of the thread. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your clear response. For now, I'm ok with setting the status message and updating the Frame/GUI via `self.update`

Comment: Sure - whatever achieves your goal :)

Comment: @mnikley ,this would be good if you are planning to do a sort of work in background while running the program, however this would also meet the goals of Ashwin.